# Python - How to keep a QComboBox's QLineEdit from adding new items

Tags: python, pyqt

Whenever you add a basic `QLineEdit` to a `QComboBox`, if you type anything into the `QComboBox` and press [Enter], the `QLineEdit` text will get added to the `QComboBox`.

Just to be clear, I still want to have the ability to manage the `QComboBox` items (add, remove, etc) like normal. In this case, only `QLineEdit` is not allowed to add new items.

I'd **very much prefer** a solution that did not require subclassing a built-in QLineEdit/QComboBox

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import functools
import sys

# Use PySide/PyQt. Doesn't matter
from Qt import QtWidgets


def print_items(combo_box):
    print([combo_box.itemText(index) for index in range(combo_box.count())])


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    window = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    line_edit.editingFinished.connect(functools.partial(print_items, window))
    window.setLineEdit(line_edit)

    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    # start writing in the QLineEdit and press [Enter]. 
    # The item is now in the QComboBox and print in the terminal


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but why not set [insert policy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#insertPolicy-prop)? Like `window.setInsertPolicy(QtWidgets.QComboBox.NoInsert)`.

Comment: Whoops, I misread the docs. I did see that but I assumed it meant "read-only". This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: no problem, docs are evasive sometimes :)